# Newbie ASP.net developer variable persisting across routines

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am building an ASP.net webpage for the first time;  I come from a VB.net background building standalone exe apps.

In my main page that is loaded upon entering user credentials, I allow a user to enter new project data or to reload and edit and then resave a project.  I have the first part done but am perplexed by the reload part.

I have a routine that grabs data from the database and stores various values as variables, e.g.,  Dim projectID as string = "".   The dim is in the top section above any sub routines.  In VB, since it is a module-level variable all routines could use that variable with its assigned value.  What I am seeing is this variable is getting reset to the blank it was in the initialization if I use "projectID" in a routine in which it wasn't assigned.

So why doesn't the variable value persist in different routines?  All sub routines are not private and the variable is at the module level?

Answer (score 0):

With ASP.NET, the life cycle of a page is pretty fixed and short lived. Hence, most values are cleaned up and not guaranteed to survive. You should look to store things in session or application state.